# Second script waits for first even though both are loaded in parallel. Why?

Tags: php, httprequest

can someone please explain to me why is loading time of test.php?q=two 2 seconds, even though both "images" are loaded in parallel? Why has sleep in test.php?q=one effect on test.php?q=two ?

Proof that they are loading concurrently and that it takes second request twice as much time to finish:

[image: parallel request]

Code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['q'])) sleep(1);
else{
?>
<img src="test.php?q=one">
<img src="test.php?q=two">
<?php
}
```

Comment: Any chance you have `session.auto_start` set?

Comment: I have session.auto_start set to 0 in php.ini

Comment: And what if you check in `phpinfo()`? What is the configuration - php, webserver, SAPI.

Comment: There is a [maximum number of parallel HTTP connections per server(domain?)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14768266/1188035), but this wouldn't reach Chrome's limit of 6. I'm thinking there must be a limitation somewhere from Apache, PHP, or the browser.

Comment: It's definitely off. http://pastebin.com/uZuxXB0T I don't think this is server misconfiguration. Does that snippet works differently for you?

Comment: @gadelat: yep, it works fine for me.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/095qcaurzaahhf7/Screenshot%202014-12-19%2010.34.04.png?dl=0

Comment: `test.php:1` is one byte smaller than `test.php:2` — so something is obviously getting added the second time around.

Comment: @l'L'l: there are several dynamic headers in response, like `Date`

Comment: Call me crazy, but can you reproduce this from another ISP? ISPs like to do weird things (block ports, restrict simultaneous connections, etc. because they can.) Hotspot your phone and see if it still persists. Or are you doing this on your local environment?

Comment: Yup I'm doing this locally in ArchLinux. But you are right guys, I tried same script in windows VM and it works fine there. So it's definitely not a problem of code.

Comment: @gadelat What does your `httpd.conf` look like?

Comment: The only reason `two` takes longer is because you've got $q set to sleep(1) twice by the time it gets to the second <img>. Try flip-flopping `q=one` with `q=two`, you'll get the same result.

Comment: httpd.conf http://pastebin.com/Xf3wimAf

Comment: @l'L'l Wat? The if-condition depends on `isset($_GET['q'])`... not content specific

Comment: According to the code shown it's loading in succession, not parallel - big difference.

Comment: @l'L'l: according to the code it must load in parallel, and it does on my machine. The code **IS** fine.

Comment: `<img src="test.php?q=one">` is called before `<img src="test.php?q=two">` — that **IS NOT** parallel, that is succession, as in one then two...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have a limit connections per IP

```
<IfModule mod_limitipconn.c>
     <Location /your-download-directory>
          MaxConnPerIP 1
     </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't. $ grep MaxConnPerIP . -ri returns no matches. Config /etc/httpd/config/extra/httpd-mpm.conf is interesting though http://pastebin.com/bYkfz099

Answer (score -2):

Might also be because this script is in a file called test.php - self-calling? If so, on the first call the `q` is not set, on the second one it is, and that's why you get a delay of 1 second.

First call (page load itself) goes without `q` being set and the `else` logic is executed, second call goes with `q=one` and the `if` logic is executed (there should be no image output) and a delay of one second occurs, the third call goes with `q=two`, again the `if` logic is executed, no image output and a delay of one additional second occurs.

Comment: What is special in "self-calling"? Not to say there is no such a thing like "self-calling" and http requests are stateless

Comment: "First call (page load itself) goes without q being set and the else logic is execute" --- no, this is completely wrong. You don't understand how php and http work, sorry.

Comment: Well what I see form the code is PHP runs the command requested, that's `sleep(1)` on each call where `q` is set. That delays the response from PHP, and images are rendered one by one by the browser, not yet sure why.

Comment: that's right. It doesn't explain why they are not running in parallel. Your answer is based on a **WRONG** assumption on how php+html works. "not yet sure why" --- that is the question.

Comment: @zerkms would you please stop attacking me while I'm trying to help YOU out?

Comment: Well, your answer is based on wild assumptions (which are incorrect). Anyway, I don't care, have fun.

Comment: The issue might be caused because the browsers are single threaded, have a look at this article: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/27/loading-scripts-without-blocking/. P.S. I'm already having fun, thx.

Comment: Nope, browsers **ARE NOT** single threaded. Browsers fetch resources in parallel without any issues. Please stop guessing.

Comment: What about PHP being limited to one process per script?

Comment: "PHP being limited to one process per script" --- this phrase makes no sense.

Comment: To clarify, this is what I'm referring to: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/worker.html. If you limit MaxSpareThreads and ThreadsPerChild to 1, it might lead to PHP running as "single-threaded".

Comment: you're referring to the things you don't understand. The phrase still makes no sense. Sorry, I'm out of this.

Comment: It is clear enough for me that the whole answer and this discussion is pointless.